# STIX mathematics font?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, design

> **EDIT**: It seems to perhaps be an issue with Firefox. Is this the case
>   for anyone? It uses STIX in Chrome,
>   but not FF.

I did a search and couldn't find any information on this.

It seems the font used for mathematics has been changed to a sans-serif font at some point. Can't be have STIX fonts back? Or at least set up MathJax to prefer STIX if it's available? (this is a possibility, see [this](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/options/HTML-CSS.html)).

While sans-serif might be bigger and easier to read for some folks, it has far less symbology than either TeX or STIX. Moreover, it doesn't even support a good amount of common math characters, such as blackboard bold R: $\mathbb{R}$ which was written `\mathbb{R}`.

MathJax has facilities to help hard-to-read mathematics, such as the zoom feature, usable by the users.

Lastly, parentheses don't always align right (for me), which came to my attention especially in my response [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28021/bounded-linear-mappings-of-banach-spaces/28025#28025).

Comment: I'm still seeing all math in a serif typeface. (Firefox 3.6 on Linux.) Can you try a [hard refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache#Mozilla_family) and see if it helps?